# Как стилизовать вкладки (CSS)

Tags: css, frontend

Я не могу понять, как растянуть вкладки (EXPRESS и LOGISTICS) на требуемую ширину и убрать отступ между ними.

Требуется:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня сейчас так: https://codepen.io/molekylko/pen/XGqjvj

```
введите сюда код
```

Буду благодарен, если кто-нибудь подскажет, что нужно подкорректировать, чтобы было как на картинке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Результат : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/qvYqoY

```css
.tabs {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 120px 0 15%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 560px;
  display: flex;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.tab,
.tab-title {
  display: inline-block;
}

.tab :checked+.tab-title {
  position: relative;
  background: #ba0000;
  top: 1px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tab-content {
  background-color: #ba0000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
}

.tab :checked+.tab-title+.tab-content {
  display: block;
}

.tab {
  background-color: #ba0000;
}

.tab label {
  width: 200px;
}

.tab-title {
  background: #ffcc00;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: none;
}

.tab-content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  height: 460px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab">

    <input type="radio" id="tab1" name="tab-group" checked>
    <label for="tab1" class="tab-title">Express</label>
    <section class="tab-content">
      Содержимое вкладки1
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="tab minus">

    <input type="radio" id="tab2" name="tab-group">

    <label for="tab2" class="tab-title">Logistics</label>

    <section class="tab-content">
      Содержимое вкладки2
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```